# Page stalls for a few seconds, then loads as normal

Tags: javascript, performance, wordpress, load

I recently moved a wordpress site over to a different server, but when the front page loads, it stalls for a few seconds, then process to load the page. Im not entirely well versed in web development. Any help?

http://phoenix-productions.tv/v2

Thanks,
Jeff

Comment: Maybe not related, but you are requesting `http://anasianscreations.co.cc/crossdomain.xml` which is responding with a 404. I would assume the huge video is the culprit, try compressing it or finding a way to lazy load it.

Answer (score 0):

Static files (images, CSS, JavaScript, sound) are loading fine. It's your PHP page that can take up to 10-15 seconds to load. Without looking at the code it's difficult to debug, but take a look at your homepage code (maybe index.php or in some theme file) and check around the area where it echos out the client login image. Always seems to pause around there for a while.

Check PHP code near:

`<a href=""><img src="http://phoenix-productions.tv/v2/wp-content/themes/phoenix/style/social-client.png" style="vertical-align:middle"></a>`

Other options might include installing and setting up caching for your website. Try the default WP cache or a plugin called SuperCache.